# Why doesn't the user agent stylesheet override styles with lower specificity?

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

Why does the * selector override the user agent stylesheet? For example, the user agent stylesheet sets the font-weight of an h1 tag to bold. Now, why does declaring `* { font-weight: lighter; }`, set the font-weight of the h1 to lighter? I would expect the user agent stylesheet to override the `*` selector because it has a specificity of 0-0-0 and the h1 (tag styles) has a specificity of 0-0-1. Or does the user agent stylesheet have an even lower specificity than 0, or does it just get overwritten by any value you declare?

Comment: Let's just think about, Why would the UA override a dev defined style ? obviously because you mean what you want, if you want UA to override a certain style don't declare it, it just doesn't make any sense for the UA to override a dev defined style, it's just there as a starting point.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I agree with that. So does that mean that the UA has no specificity at all, and just gets overwritten by whatever you declare?